# Displaying a string with special chars in xaml wp8

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

i´m having a trouble to display a string value, that i'm binding to a textblock, the problem is that, the string has a value like this -> Corrección and when i display that value has some strange characters, i already try to encode that string to utf-8 but the problem still there, the question is, there is some namespace that i had to incle at phone label? or there is some way to encode directly to the textblock label ? please guys need some help here.

the code is the next.

```
//on the cs file i have something like this

string someString= "Acción de la niñes";
```

and this value is binding to a textblock like this

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding}" />
```

so the display value has strange chars at the "ó" and the "ñ"

Again i hope someone can help i will be very thankful with all of you

Comment: This might be an encoding problem or a display problem. What kind of strange chars do you see?

Comment: in the most of them are rhombus that has an ->? inside

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds like an encoding problem. Make sure that your files (XAML, code, resources) use a proper Unicode encoding such as UTF8.

Comment: it needs to add some namespace or something like that ??

Comment: the problem stills there U.u, i have make sure that the coding of the file is OK, and when i run the simulator, this symbol ->� appears instead of the right char

Comment: i´m so sorry the trouble was at the DB encoding, U.u, but really thankful with you